# Add CSS3 Button to HTML Page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following button in between my style tags:

```
<style>
 .myButton {
   border-top: 1px solid #96d1f8;
   background: #65a9d7;
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#3e779d), to(#65a9d7));
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3e779d, #65a9d7);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3e779d, #65a9d7);
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3e779d, #65a9d7);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3e779d, #65a9d7);
   padding: 5px 10px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
   -moz-border-radius: 8px;
   border-radius: 8px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.4) 0 1px 0;
   color: white;
   font-size: 14px;
   font-family: Georgia, serif;
   text-decoration: none;
   vertical-align: middle;
   }
.myButton:hover {
   border-top-color: #28597a;
   background: #28597a;
   color: #ccc;
   }
.myButton:active {
   border-top-color: #1b435e;
   background: #1b435e;
   }

</style>
```

**Question:**

How would I add the button to my HTML page with the `ID` of `btnAdd`
Is this the correct way of doing it:

```
<button class="myButton" id="btnAdd" /> Add </button>
```

Comment: What relevance does the CSS have to your question? I think you can safely remove it to avoid confusion

Comment: @SexyTurnip - I was just showing the button I created.

Comment: What do you mean add the button to your HTML page? when would it be added?

Comment: @YourConscious - The button I customized in CSS, how would I add it to the html file, and register the button event listener.

Comment: can you explain what you mean by 'register' what is this functionality? And when would this occur, onClick?

Comment: Can you just tell us what your trying to do from a high level?

Comment: Yes, OnClick. I want to register the button to the eventListner that I provide in my code above.

Comment: @YourConscious - Check my updated post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.)**

```
<a class="myButton" id="btnAdd"> Add </a>
```

**2.)**

and then this? *(full code below)*

---

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){

});

function myFunc(){ alert('Hey Hey Hey, is that a mirror in your pocket?'); }
    
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
        document.getElementById('btnAdd').addEventListener('click', myFunc);
    });
```

```css
.myButton {
   border-top: 1px solid #96d1f8;
   background: #65a9d7;
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#3e779d), to(#65a9d7));
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3e779d, #65a9d7);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3e779d, #65a9d7);
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3e779d, #65a9d7);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3e779d, #65a9d7);
   padding: 5px 10px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
   -moz-border-radius: 8px;
   border-radius: 8px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.4) 0 1px 0;
   color: white;
   font-size: 14px;
   font-family: Georgia, serif;
   text-decoration: none;
   vertical-align: middle;
   }
.myButton:hover {
   border-top-color: #28597a;
   background: #28597a;
   color: #ccc;
   }
.myButton:active {
   border-top-color: #1b435e;
   background: #1b435e;
   }
```

```html
<a class="myButton" id="btnAdd" href="#"> Add </a>
```

**3.)** **Based on comment request, can also do it this way:**

```
<p>This example uses the addEventListener() method to attach a click event to a button.</p>

<a class="myButton" id="btnAdd" href="#"> Add </a>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The addEventListener() method is not supported in Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
document.getElementById("btnAdd").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
});
</script>
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/znxzLwL3/2/)

**4.)** And also without using `href=""` in the `<a>` tag

[**JSFIDDLE (no link in a tag)**](https://jsfiddle.net/znxzLwL3/3/)

Comment: does the <a href link have to be there?

Comment: @SexyTurnip - I did it the way I posted in my code above, and it worked, I just wanted to know if that was the proper practice.

Comment: @SexyTurnip - In my code above you mean the <button class="myButton" id="btnAdd" /> Add </button>

Comment: The button doesn't show correctly? What is wrong with the way I did it in my above code?

Comment: @SexyTurnip Yes, that was a typo, sorry guys. Of course the close tag would it turn be a </a>

Comment: @YourConscious - THANK YOU! Now it works, However, why do I need <a href? Can I add the button without it?

Comment: Just remove it, if you must.

Comment: @YourConscious - How would you add the button with the a href?

Comment: @YourConscious - Could I add the event listener as suggested here? http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp

Comment: Yeah, why not I just added some extra stuff ;) Glad to help!

Comment: @YourConscious - Much appricated one more thing could you show me how to so the button without the  a href

Comment: @YourConscious- Just for my own understanding, because its a customized button you have to say <a class right? Cause its not a normal button, correct?

Comment: Yes. Class name correlates with the styles that make it look a certain way. I updated my Jsfiddle links with the styles.

Answer (score 0):

The correct format would be:

```
<button class="myButton" id="btnAdd">Add</button>
```

What you posted is a mixture between a standard tag and a [self-closing tag](http://xahlee.info/js/html5_non-closing_tag.html). If you use a self-closing tag, you do not need the trailing enclosure (`</button>` in this case), but `button` is not an element that supports self-closing tags so a standard tag enclosure should be used.